# SQL Join A and B using row from each exactly once

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to write some sql that associates users with transactions. There are two tables created by separate systems which I cannot change. The one table has the user_id, an sku and some other info about the transaction, the second table has an sku and extra info about the transaction, the only field the two tables share is the sku, and none of the other fields can be used to correlate the rows in the different tables.

This is obviously not enough info to correctly link the information in the two tables, so I want to make a best effort. The added complication is that the table with the user_ids is sometimes missing rows.
 Basically, given two tables like this:

```
+----------+-------+--------------------+
| user_id  |  sku  | metadata_table_one |
+----------+-------+--------------------+
|        1 | sku_1 | foo_1              |
|        2 | sku_1 | foo_2              |
|        3 | sku_2 | foo_3              |
+----------+-------+--------------------+
```

and

```
+-------+--------------------+
|  sku  | metadata_table_two |
+-------+--------------------+
| sku_1 | bar_a              |
| sku_1 | bar_b              |
| sku_1 | bar_c              |
| sku_2 | bar_d              |
+-------+--------------------+
```

I want to end up with a table like this:

```
+-------+---------+--------------------+--------------------+
|  sku  | user_id | metadata_table_two | metadata_table_one |
+-------+---------+--------------------+--------------------+
| sku_1 | 1       | bar_a              | foo_1              |
| sku_1 | 2       | bar_b              | foo_2              |
| sku_1 | null    | bar_c              | null               |
| sku_2 | 3       | bar_d              | foo_3              |
+-------+---------+--------------------+--------------------+
```

Where I'm not worried about which user_id gets associated to which row in the second table, as long as each one appears exactly once. I know this association is random and potentially not very useful, but other rows we associate correctly (with a field that's missing from these rows) and we're happy with a random guess for the remaining rows.

Comment: You have a typo in your expected output table in the last row, under the `metadata_table_two` column.  Instead of `foo_a`, the value should be `bar_d`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using MySQL 8+, then `ROW_NUMBER` comes in handy here:

```
WITH cte1 AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY sku ORDER BY user_id) rn
    FROM users
),
cte2 AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY sku ORDER BY metadata_table_two) rn
    FROM skus
)

SELECT
    t2.sku,
    t1.user_id,
    t2.metadata_table_two,
    t1.metadata_table_one
FROM cte2 t2
LEFT JOIN cte1 t1
    ON t2.sku = t1.sku AND t2.rn = t1.rn
ORDER BY
    t2.sku,
    t2.metadata_table_two;
```

[image: screen capture of demo below]

### Demo

Answer (score 0):

If you are running an earlier version than MySql 8 and do not wish to simulate row numbers, then the following should work. Note that it will return different results than the example you would like to end up with. But you also said that "you are not worried about which user_id gets associated to which row in the second table, as long as each one appears exactly once." I believe the following satisfies that requirement:

```
SELECT s.sku, u.user_id, s.metadata_table_two, u.metadata_table_one
FROM sku_table s LEFT JOIN user_table u
   ON s.sku = u.sku and u.user_id = (select min(user_id) from user_table where sku = s.sku)
ORDER BY s.sku, s.metadata_table_two;
```

The results (for some reason the columns returned on DB Fiddle are not in the same order as specified in the `select` clause):

```
| sku   | metadata_table_two | user_id | metadata_table_one |
| ----- | ------------------ | ------- | ------------------ |
| sku_1 | bar_a              | 1       | foo1               |
| sku_1 | bar_b              | 1       | foo1               |
| sku_1 | bar_c              | 1       | foo1               |
| sku_2 | bar_d              | 3       | foo3               |
```

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/ai2nHuDCrQKGTBppcSvbCm/0)

Comment: Thanks! But this associates multiple rows from the one table with the same row from the table with user_id s in it. Fortunately the partition approach should work for me.